# why is a non null postgres column with default throwing a constraint error?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, null, default-value

In Postgres I have a not null column with default set to false. I am using a spring boot JPA/hibernate java app to write to this table. My understanding is with the default value if null is passed it should set it to the default. But I am getting the below exception. Other types like character seem to work. How do I get it to correctly use the default if null is passed?

[image]
[image]

Comment: No a `DEFAULT` is used if no value is passed and only on `INSERT`. `NULL` is a value, an unknown one but a value, so `DEFAULT` is not invoked and you trip the `NOT NULL` constraint. To get this to work just don't supply a value for the field. See here [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) *DEFAULT default_expr* for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The default value is used if **no value** is passed for that column, not if a `null` is explicitly passed.

You didn't share your Hibernate code, so I can't comment on it, but you need to change the query so it will **omit** the `is_custom` column from the `insert` statement.

Comment: the column is just a standard column so not sure what else I would share: @Column(name = "is_custom") Boolean isCustom; Is there any JPA annotation where I can omit this in the query if the value is null? In the mean time I just updated all my code to always set a value. Still would like to understand what the best practice is. Im directly using crud repository and I dont have any custom queries. JPA / Hibernate are generating the sql directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the database to use the default value you set for the column you can do this with your entity variable.

@Column(name = "is_custom", insertable = false)

This will remove the column from the insert and the database will assign the default value from your table definition.

Another way is to set the default value as a column definition.

@Column(name = "is_custom", columnDefinition = "boolean default false")